# How to make contour plot from this function in MATLAB R2013a?

Tags: matlab, contour

```
f(x,y)= x^5 + x^4- 2x^2 y + y^2
```

I already tried to run it in MATLAB but it's failed.

Comment: What did you try to run? Exactly this? Because that's obviously not much, declare `x` and `y` for starters; [`contour`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html) was present already in R2013a, so what's the actual problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to first set x and y as certain vectors.
This could give you a hint of what your code should look like:

```
x=0:0.1:10;
y=0:0.1:10;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z=X.^5 + X.^4- 2*X.^(2)+Y + Y.^2;
figure;
contour(X,Y,Z);
```